# Magento 2 selecting specific collection fields doesn't working

Tags: php, collections, zend-framework, magento2

I have this piece of code

```
$collection->getSelect()
        ->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
        ->columns(["driver_name" => new \Zend_Db_expr("CONCAT(driver.first_name, driver.last_name)")])
        ->columns(["delivery_date" => 'order.cedDeliveryDate'])
        ->columns(["delivery_timeslot" => 'order.cedTimestamp'])
        ->join(
            ['driver' => $collection->getTable('magenative_mobidelivery_driver')],
            'main_table.driver_id = driver.id'
        )
        ->join(
            ['order' => $collection->getTable('sales_order')],
            'main_table.increment_id = order.increment_id'
        );
```

I am trying to select only the specific fields which is driver name, delivery date  and timeslot of the orders. but when I try to print it by using this code

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($collection->getData()[0]);die;
```

It still printing all the fields instead of the specific  fields mentioned above.

```
Array
(
    [driver_name] => NayminSoe
    [delivery_date] => 2019-12-12 00:00:00
    [delivery_timeslot] => 14:00 - 18:00
    [id] => 3
    [role] => driver
    [first_name] => Naymin
    [last_name] => Soe
    [password] => naymin123
    [user_name] => naymin
    [email] => naymin@wine.delivery
    [store_id] => 1
    [status] => out_for_delivery
    [mobile_number] => 456
    [image] => 
    [is_do] => 
    [entity_id] => 2115
    [state] => complete
    [coupon_code] => 
    [protect_code] => 04bf460b05586d0a4ce695facb1e0b89
    [shipping_description] => Marketplace Rates
    [is_virtual] => 0
    [customer_id] => 1738
    [base_discount_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_discount_canceled] => 
    [base_discount_invoiced] => 0.0000
    [base_discount_refunded] => 
    [base_grand_total] => 116.0000
    [base_shipping_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_shipping_canceled] => 
    [base_shipping_invoiced] => 0.0000
    [base_shipping_refunded] => 
    [base_shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_shipping_tax_refunded] => 
    [base_subtotal] => 99.0700
    [base_subtotal_canceled] => 
    [base_subtotal_invoiced] => 99.0700
    [base_subtotal_refunded] => 
    [base_tax_amount] => 6.9300
    [base_tax_canceled] => 
    [base_tax_invoiced] => 6.9300
    [base_tax_refunded] => 
    [base_to_global_rate] => 1.0000
    [base_to_order_rate] => 1.0000
    [base_total_canceled] => 
    [base_total_invoiced] => 116.0000
    [base_total_invoiced_cost] => 0.0000
    [base_total_offline_refunded] => 
    [base_total_online_refunded] => 
    [base_total_paid] => 116.0000
    [base_total_qty_ordered] => 
    [base_total_refunded] => 
    [discount_amount] => 0.0000
    [discount_canceled] => 
    [discount_invoiced] => 0.0000
    [discount_refunded] => 
    [grand_total] => 116.0000
    [shipping_amount] => 0.0000
    [shipping_canceled] => 
    [shipping_invoiced] => 0.0000
    [shipping_refunded] => 
    [shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000
    [shipping_tax_refunded] => 
    [store_to_base_rate] => 0.0000
    [store_to_order_rate] => 0.0000
    [subtotal] => 99.0700
    [subtotal_canceled] => 
    [subtotal_invoiced] => 99.0700
    [subtotal_refunded] => 
    [tax_amount] => 6.9300
    [tax_canceled] => 
    [tax_invoiced] => 6.9300
    [tax_refunded] => 
    [total_canceled] => 
    [total_invoiced] => 116.0000
    [total_offline_refunded] => 
    [total_online_refunded] => 
    [total_paid] => 116.0000
    [total_qty_ordered] => 2.0000
    [total_refunded] => 
    [can_ship_partially] => 
    [can_ship_partially_item] => 
    [customer_is_guest] => 0
    [customer_note_notify] => 1
    [billing_address_id] => 3580
    [customer_group_id] => 1
    [edit_increment] => 
    [email_sent] => 1
    [send_email] => 1
    [forced_shipment_with_invoice] => 
    [payment_auth_expiration] => 
    [quote_address_id] => 
    [quote_id] => 3308
    [shipping_address_id] => 3579
    [adjustment_negative] => 
    [adjustment_positive] => 
    [base_adjustment_negative] => 
    [base_adjustment_positive] => 
    [base_shipping_discount_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_subtotal_incl_tax] => 106.0000
    [base_total_due] => 0.0000
    [payment_authorization_amount] => 
    [shipping_discount_amount] => 0.0000
    [subtotal_incl_tax] => 106.0000
    [total_due] => 0.0000
    [weight] => 0.8000
    [customer_dob] => 
    [increment_id] => SOSG19121115183791
    [applied_rule_ids] => 
    [base_currency_code] => SGD
    [customer_email] => mark.457240@gmail.com
    [customer_firstname] => Mark
    [customer_lastname] => Lauw
    [customer_middlename] => 
    [customer_prefix] => 
    [customer_suffix] => 
    [customer_taxvat] => 
    [discount_description] => 
    [ext_customer_id] => 
    [ext_order_id] => 
    [global_currency_code] => SGD
    [hold_before_state] => 
    [hold_before_status] => 
    [order_currency_code] => SGD
    [original_increment_id] => 
    [relation_child_id] => 
    [relation_child_real_id] => 
    [relation_parent_id] => 
    [relation_parent_real_id] => 
    [remote_ip] => 
    [shipping_method] => vendor_rates_freeshipping_freesh
    [store_currency_code] => SGD
    [store_name] => Wine.Delivery Singapore
Wine.Del
    [x_forwarded_for] => 
    [customer_note] => 
    [created_at] => 2019-12-11 07:18:49
    [updated_at] => 2019-12-16 04:50:33
    [total_item_count] => 2
    [customer_gender] => 
    [discount_tax_compensation_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_discount_tax_compensation_amount] => 0.0000
    [shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amnt] => 
    [discount_tax_compensation_invoiced] => 0.0000
    [base_discount_tax_compensation_invoiced] => 0.0000
    [discount_tax_compensation_refunded] => 
    [base_discount_tax_compensation_refunded] => 
    [shipping_incl_tax] => 0.0000
    [base_shipping_incl_tax] => 0.0000
    [coupon_rule_name] => 
    [gift_message_id] => 
    [paypal_ipn_customer_notified] => 0
    [cedDeliveryDate] => 2019-12-12 00:00:00
    [cedTimestamp] => 14:00 - 18:00
    [cedDeliveryComment] => 
    [delivered] => 1
    [wdgift] => 
    [surcharge] => 10
    [order_note] => 
    [packed] => 0
    [require_delivery_photo] => 
)
```

Expected Result : Only include the specific fields.

Actual Result : All fields were being included.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed the third parameter.

```
$collection->getSelect()
    ->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
    ->columns(["driver_name" => new \Zend_Db_expr("CONCAT(driver.first_name, driver.last_name)")])
    ->columns(["delivery_date" => 'order.cedDeliveryDate'])
    ->columns(["delivery_timeslot" => 'order.cedTimestamp'])
    ->join(
        ['driver' => $collection->getTable('magenative_mobidelivery_driver')],
        'main_table.driver_id = driver.id',
        []

    )
    ->join(
        ['order' => $collection->getTable('sales_order')],
        'main_table.increment_id = order.increment_id',
        []
    );
```